# The benefit of PWA in terms of offline use of web app

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I was learning React and later came across the term called progressive web app. Also, one of the benefits of pwa is that it allows to use a web app even with the lack of the Internet. The question is what is the benefit of PWA when there is no Internet, that is, say, the Internet is off and we continue using our web app and, for example, we want to delete a certain data by sending DELETE request to server but since there is no Internet, how is it gonna work? All in all, I am wondering how a web app being PWA will handle requests to server since there is no Internet connection? Will the app store the history of http requests in memory and once there is Internet connection, all of those requests are sent to server right away?

Answer (score 0):

yes we can handle this scenario using PWA concept,
here is a bit explanation on similar content: https://blog.formpl.us/how-to-handle-post-put-requests-in-offline-applications-using-service-workers-indexedb-and-da7d0798a9ab